# Zurb Foundation Top-Bar Link Background not displaying correctly

Tags: css, zurb-foundation-5

I am using Zurb Foundation 5 in my app.

The settings file has been updated so that the top-bar will have a custom look and feel. The top-bar looks perfect but I can't seem to get the top-bar link backgrounds to play along.

My settings are as follows:

```
$topbar-bg-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
$topbar-bg: $topbar-bg-color;
$topbar-link-bg: inherit;
$topbar-link-bg-color-hover: inherit;
$topbar-link-bg-hover: inherit;
```

The top-bar has a Opaque white color, yet the links are presented with a black (dark) background.

I have tried the following as well:

1. Setting the $topbar-link-* to transparent (Still Black)
2. Manually setting $topbar-link-* to $topbar-bg-color (Now links have a white background but it's not Opaque)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of how it looks and how you want it to look.

Comment: @WouterFlorijn or better yet, a JSBin/JSFiddle